# Basic question regarding addition in $p$-adic integers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I just learned $p$-adic integers and I am confused about something. I was wondering if someone could possibly explain me how it is done. 
Suppose I have $\bar{a} = 1 + 0 \cdot p + 0 \cdot p^2 + 0 \cdot p^3 + ... $
and $\bar{b} = 0 + (p-1) \cdot p + (p-1) \cdot p^2 + (p-1) \cdot p^3 + ... $
I know $\mathbb{Z}_p$ forms a ring, but I was wondering what
$\bar{a} - \bar{b}$ was?

Is the situation different from $1 - 0.9999... = 0$ in real numbers?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that $\bar{b} + 1\cdot p = 0$, so that $-\bar{b} = 1\cdot p$. Then we can compute $\bar{a} - \bar{b} = 1 + 1\cdot p$.

Comment: I see. Thank you! Are there situations like $1 - 0.999999... = 0$ in $p$-adic integers (where one element may have two different representations)?

Comment: Try to construct such an example and see if you are able to.